# Can I replace multiform uploads by using base64 in HTTP uploads?

Tags: rest, api, http, upload, base64

Hey so this might be  a broad question, but I'm currently designing a REST api and I've currently been using multipart-form to upload files. The thing is that I would like to upload a file in a Patch request, which doesn't allow multipart data, but does allow the data to be uploaded in the body of the request. I would like to have one way to upload files to be standard in my API. Should I stick with multipart or would it be okay to just attach a base64 string with a mimetype in the body of my request? Would there be any limitations to the base64 method? I'm mostly planning to upload pictures no more than 3MB if that makes a difference.

Comment: 1) why PATCH, not PUT? 2) why base64 at all?

Comment: @JulianReschke PATCH is according to HTTP the method used for partially modifying an object (which I am) while PUT is supposed to completely replace an object. Also Base64 because it's a good way to encode files into JSON

Comment: 1) I didn't get that uploading a file is a partial update... In any case. 2) Why don't you just send the file as-is? Why encode it in the first place?

Comment: @JulianReschke Because PATCH requests don't allow multipart data

Comment: a) You could use multipart with PATCH; you just would need to define what multipart means in the context of PATCH; b) why do you want to use multipart in the first place?